# Calling firebase function results in Internal Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am calling a simple firebase function from a web app I get an INTERNAL error. Can someone please suggest where I could be going wrong.

I have seen similar questions but they don't answer the issue I am facing.

I can confirm that the function has been deployed to the firebase.

By pasting the below link in the browser I get a response. 
    https://us-central1-cureme-dac13.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld

**index.js** file has the code (Firebase cloud functions are defined in index.js)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

**webApp.js** has the below code (Client/Website)

```
var messageA = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('helloWorld');

messageA().then(function(result) {

  console.log("resultFromFirebaseFunctionCall: "+result)

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Getting the Error details.
  var code      = error.code;
  var message   = error.message;
  var details   = error.details;
  // ...
  console.log("error.message: "+error.message+" error.code: "+error.code+" error.details: "+error.details)
  // Prints: error.message: INTERNAL error.code: internal error.details: undefined
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing up [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTPS Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

By doing

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(...)
```

you define an HTTPS Cloud Function,

but by doing

```
var messageA = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('helloWorld');
messageA().then(function(result) {...});
```

in your client/front-end, you actually call a Callable Cloud Function.

---

You should either change your Cloud Function to a Callable one, or call/invoque the `helloWorld` HTTPS Cloud Function by sending an HTTP GET Request to the Cloud Function URL (Similarly to the way you did in your browser by "pasting the  `https://us-central1-cureme-dac13.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld` link in the browser").

For example, by using the [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library, you would do:

```
axios.get('https://us-central1-cureme-dac13.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please help on this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61116549/2534233